# Access subs or values from a dynamically created UserControl by the MainControl

Tags: vb.net, types, dynamic, user-controls

Hello I've a form like this:

```
--------------------------------
|BTN|BTN|BTN|                   |    
--------------------------------
|                              |
|            tabControl        |
|                              |
--------------------------------
```

Because I've a hundreds of usercontrols I try to open them in an elegant way this this procedure:

```
    Private Function OpenProg(ByVal prognr As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim prow = (From p In ds.tblPrograms Where p.ProgramID = prognr).ToList
        Dim found As Boolean = True

        If prow.Count > 0 Then
            Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly
            Dim t As System.Type = a.[GetType]("<SoftwareName>.usc" & prow(0).ProgramID)
            If t IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim o As Object = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, True)
                Dim usc As System.Windows.Forms.UserControl = DirectCast(o, System.Windows.Forms.UserControl)
                Dim tabPage As New XtraTabPage
                tabPage.Text = prow(0).ProgramName
                tabPage.Tag = prow(0).ProgramID
                tabCtrl.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
                tabPage.Controls.Add(usc)
                usc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                tabCtrl.SelectedTabPage = tabPage
            End If
        Else
            found = False
        End If
        Return found
    End Function
```

In this way a new usercontrol with the corresponding usercontrolID and tab is created.

But I don't know how to access this Usercontrol for example after pressing a button. That's what I've written for the save-button:

```
    Private Sub bbiSave_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles bbiSave.ItemClick
        Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly
        Dim t As System.Type = a.[GetType]("<SoftwareName>.usc" & CInt(e.Item.Tag))
        For Each ctr As System.Windows.Forms.Control In tabCtrl.SelectedTabPage.Controls
            If ctr.Name = "usc" & CInt(e.Item.Tag) Then

                Dim usc As System.Windows.Forms.UserControl = TryCast(ctr, t) '<- incorrect, t is not defined
            End If
        Next



    End Sub
```

But I'ld like to access Save() or a Textfield, etc.:

```
Partial Public Class usc10
    ...

    Public Sub Save()
        ... something
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of course I'm able to run it with typed Types f.e. (Dim usc As New usc10; usc.Save), but I don't know how to archieve this with dynamic types.

Comment: This seems like the perfect candidate for an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/) that has a `Save()` method in it. If all of your UserControls **Implement** that Interface, then you can simply cast any of them to that specific Interface type and call the `Save()` method.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, I asked ChatGPT, I thought he solved the Problem, but did not, but he helped me to find a solution:

```
Private Sub bbiSave_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles bbiSave.ItemClick
    For Each ctr As UserControl In tabCtrl.SelectedTabPage.Controls
        If ctr.Name = "usc" & CInt(e.Item.Tag) Then
            ctr.GetType().GetMethod("Save").Invoke(ctr, Nothing) '<-- This is the key
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Idle_Mind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2330053/idle-mind) mentioned I should use **Implement**, to write a better code. Here is my solution, in case someone has a similar problem:

Creating a Custom Class, Expanding the UserControl:

```
Public Class CustomUserControl
   Inherits UserControl

   Public Event SaveClicked As EventHandler
   Sub OnSaveClicked(e As EventArgs)
       RaiseEvent SaveClicked(Me, e)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Changing the **Inherits** in usercontrolname.Designer.vb

```
Partial Class usc0
   Inherits CustomUserControl
   [...]
End Class
```

Adding to usercontrolname.vb the following code:

```
Public Sub Save(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SaveClicked
   [...]
End Sub
```

Calling the Sub in the Main Form:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        For Each ctr As CustomUserControl In tabCtrl.SelectedTabPage.Controls
            ctr.OnSaveClicked(EventArgs.Empty)
        Next
End Sub
```